# How to implement user registration with the Zotonic mod_signup module?

Tags: zotonic

I would like users to be able to sign up a website made with Zotonic. According to the release notes of version 0.5.0, I should use the mod_signup module.

What is the correct way to use this module in a website? I've tried to create a "signup" page and to include the templates of mod_signup, without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enable the mod_signup module you will be able to use the signup form on the '/signup' page.  Check the dispatch rules of mod_signup.

You will also need to enable mod_emailer and (optionally) mod_acl_simple_roles (disable mod_acl_adminonly).

Available config keys are:

- `mod_signup.request_confirm` set to 0 or 1 to disable or enable confirmation e-mails
- `mod_signup.member_category` set to the category for the new members (defaults to `person`)
- `mod_signup.member_visible_for` the visibility of the new members, defaults to 0 (world viewable), choose 1 for only visible for members.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've just reinstalled Zotonic and tried do what you suggest, with mod_signup.request_confirm = 0. Unfortunately, when I open the '/signup' page I'm immediately redirected to the Site Administrator's page ('/page/1'). Is there anything missing? Do I have to create the 'signup' page specifically? Do I have to create a role for users with ACL Simple Roles?

Comment: You are redirected because you are already an user.  Log off and try again.